# Packaging deb: how to handle potentially missing dependencies

Tags: debian, ubuntu, dependencies, packaging, deb

## Problem:

I'm trying to create a DEB package from my own sources.
Everything is fine except handling the dependencies.

As I understand, the most genuine way to mark the dependencies is to list them in the `Depends` section of the `control` file. My application requires two packages (`aapt` and `zipalign`) which are present **only** in the recent Debian (≥ *jessie*) and Ubuntu (≥ *willy*) repositories, so there would definitely be a problem installing my .deb on the older ones.

## Ideas:

Several thoughts on this question:

- Install the needed standalone binaries (as a part of my .deb) to `/usr/bin`.

  - **PRO**: The needed dependencies are present in my package as stand-alone binaries, so the `Depends` section won't be used, and the missing repository packages won't be a problem.
  - **CON**: If the destination binaries already exist on the target machine as a part of another package, `dpkg` will encounter an error, and forcing the user to pass `--force-overwrite` option is not a greatest idea.
- Install the needed standalone binaries (as a part of my .deb) to `/usr/share/myapp`.

  - **PRO**: The application uses its own isolated directory for the third-party binaries, so it does not alter the potentially existing packages (and, again, the `Depends` section is no longer needed).
  - **CON**: The `share` directory is intended for an architecture-independent data, which the binaries are not.
- Install the whole application to the `/opt/myapp` directory.

  - **PRO**: This method does not violate the FHS structure and keeps the files in a totally isolated directory.
  - **CON**: However, this is not an authentic UNIX way, especially for the opensource software.
- Use the `Recommends` section instead of `Depends` for a weaker relation and provide some instructions to users on how to get the lacking packages.

  - **CON**: The .deb package itself loses the point.

None of these methods seems right to me. Are there any standard ways to handle this problem, did I miss some obvious solution? For example, some kind of conditional installation would be very helpful (install the third-party binaries only if the `which` command outputs nothing, etc.).

Any thoughts and advises would be appreciated.

Comment: There's solution 1b: provide builds under a name like `myapp-zipalign` and let your tool either fall back on that name or have configurable tool names.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz That is an interesting solution. Could you please add your comment as an answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide (in addition to your main package) separate packages `aapt` and `zipalign`. Make sure they have `~` in their version (like this: `zipalign-21-4~kefir1.deb`). Then put them in your repository togheter with your main package which has `Depends: aapt, zipalign` (I use easy `reprepro` for hosting my repository, it's not hard).

This is *the* Debian way (the same way **backports.debian.org** works) - if system is Jessie and provides `aapt`, that will be used (as you package has tilde in version, it is only used as last resort). If the system is older Debian, only then your extra packages will be pulled. And the users get the benefit of easy-to-get upgrades/security fixes to your packages.

Additinal advantage is that on upgrade on Jessie, official packages will be pulled and overwrite your older extra pacakges (unless you specifically depend on specific version or extra packages, of course). And so you do not have old/duplicate versions hanging around, and users get additional benefits of debian security team patches etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, +1. However, if I understand correctly, this method involves creating a personal repository which needs a server to be hosted on (and the local one makes the `deb` package useless for other users).

Comment: @kefir500 yes. You need to distribute your .deb package somehow, and that is usually done by putting it up on some website for download. Repository is nothing more than files in few directories on some website. While you could possibly send users .deb files via email, or putting them on dropbox or something, that is not common. And even if you do that, having separate .deb files as explained would still benefit you and your users better than other alternatives (for example, upgrading to Jessie would automatically upgrade those obsolete binaries even if you do not have repository)